# App crashes on tesflight only with "SyscallError: setpriority No such process" error

Tags: ios, crash, testflight

I have this issue where our application runs fine in Xcode, runs fine in the simulator but crashes when you install the app via TestFlight on an iphone 6 only.

If i download the app via testflight on my test iphone 11 (ios15.1) then it works fine; if i plug in the iphone 6(ios 12.5.4) into my Mac and install the app via Xcode that way it also works fine.

The issue only seems to appear when i install the app via testflight on the iphone 6.

When you run the app the  splash screen appears and then the app closes right away

I have then used xcode -> window -> devices -> Console to view the error:

[image: Our app is called snow]

Snow is the name of our app is called Snow and it appears to throw the error:

**[Snow:503] SyscallError: setpriority(PRIO_DARWIN_ROLE, 503, 3): No such process**

Does anyone know what this means or what the issue could be?

I appreciate there is not much information,but i am finding it tough to diagnose

Comment: That's a tough one. Do you have Crashlytics integrated?

Comment: No we do not, this is something i have thought about suggesting to at least try and find the issue

Comment: In my case, I have crashlytics integrated but it doesn't help. The app crashes during startup so that crashlytics doesn't have chance to upload/record any log. I've checked Xcode's Organizer>crahses and the crash log says `NO_CRASH_STACK`. When entering the stack there are only two terms `5 _dyld_start` and `0 __abort_with_payload`. No further information. iPhone 6 only, too.